# Best way to force a Sectoid to lose Mind Control?

Tags: xcom-2

Help, what's the best way to force a Sectoid to relinquish mind control on one of my units?   Bullets and melee are ok, but the % chance to hit is killing me as it's often that it misses and I take serious damage the next turn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flashbangs are your answer, as a flashbang that explodes in range of a Sectoid will **100%** of the time force the Sectoid to relinquish mind control over a teammates.

Note that once done so, the Sectoid will no longer be able to use any alien abilities and will default to ranged weaponry.

Comment: Flashbanging sectoids also gets rid of psi zombies quite handily.